Managing/Avoiding delegation with Cloud DNS Zones in multiple GCP Projects
I am using Terraform to manage infra in a GCP Project.
The Terraform creates a DNS Zone with "dns_name" = "customer1.mycompany.com".
The Nameservers for this zone are:
ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com.

"mycompany.com" DNS is actually managed by another DNS Service provider, but this is not a problem because I can still delegate "customer1.mycompany.com" to those GCP Nameservers without a problem.
However, I now want run 20 "copies" of this infra which is managed by Terraform, with each copy running in its own GCP Project.
For example, in the 2nd "copy" of this infra, there would be another DNS Zone in its own project with "dns_name" = "customer2.mycompany.com".
This DNS Zone might have different nameservers. E.g:
ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.

The problem is, I will now need to delegate ""customer2.mycompany.com" at the other DNS Service Provider.
And this will become difficult to manage once there are 20 "copies" of this infra which all need DNS delegation
If needed, I do have the ability at my Domain name register to point "mycompany.com" to any Nameservers I like.
Can anyone suggest a tidy solution to my problem?
I did consider one possible solution, which involves creating an extra GCP Project just to manage DNS. This project would also be managed by Terraform.
I would create a DNS Zone with "dns_name" = "mycompany.com". I would set my Domain Name register to point "mycompany.com" to that GCP Zones Nameservers. The Terraform would also create extra records to perform all of the subdomain delegation to the DNS Zones in the other 20 projects
But this seems like a lot more work.
Is there some better way to solve this which I have not considered?
